# How can I add without having to use an arithmetic operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to figure out how to add without having to use the '+' sign. I'm using Winhugs as a compiler.

Let's say,
cookies = 10, chocolate = 5, cake = 20

if I enter,

> cookies 1 chocolate 1

output should be,

> 15

here's what I have

```
cookies :: Int -> Int
cookies 1 = 10
cookies n = 10 + cookies (n-1)

chocolate :: Int -> Int
chocolate 1 = 5
chocolate n = 5 + chocolate (n-1)
```

i have to enter,

> cookies 1 + chocolate 1

in order to get 15. Is there another way around this?

I also tried using recursive types but I still find it very confusing. I tried this one too but I can only add two items and I'd always have to input cookies:

```
cookies ::  Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int 
cookies x item y = (x * 20) + item y

cake :: Int -> Int
cake 1 = 20
cake n = 20 + cake (n-1)

chocolate :: Int -> Int
chocolate 1 = 5
chocolate n = 5 + chocolate (n-1)
```

also, I cannot enter just cookies as it should always have another item with it.

> cookies 1
>
> ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
>
> *** Expression : cookies 1
>
> *** Of type    : (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int

I'm sorry for the very noob question. Thank you to everyone who can help!

** UPDATE **
I know I could use a different compiler but it's what's being taught in school and it's the compiler we need to use for our project as well :(

Comment: Winhugs is obsolete. Please consider using a more modern compiler, GHC, and for a more well-rounded experience, you could use [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/)

Comment: i would but it's the compiler that we're being taught to use in school :(

Comment: @Mel that may be, but here you're clearly straying into territory that's not covered by school curriculum, and may quite possibly not be doable with Hugs at all. In fact it's debatable whether it makes any _sense_ to do it, still... you _should_ use GHC, and nobody at school can seriously mind you doing that. They just probably think Hugs is easier.

Comment: This is more like a domain-specific language (DSL) than a function.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why you want all of this. What you're trying to implement is called [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). Haskell doesn't really support these, and I really don't believe it makes sense to use them for your application. What's wrong with `cookies 1 + chocolate 2`?

That said, the Haskell2010 / GHC-Haskell type system is sufficiently flexible to allow hacking together variadic functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Crumbles c where
  crumble :: Int -> c
instance Crumbles Int where
  crumble = id
instance (f ~ (Int -> Int), i ~ Int, Crumbles c) => Crumbles (f -> i -> c) where
  crumble acc f i = crumble $ f i + acc
```

Now you can do

```
cookies :: Crumbles c => Int -> c
cookies n = crumble $ n*10

chocolate :: Crumbles c => Int -> c
chocolate n = crumble $ n*5

goodies :: [Int]
goodies = [ cookies 1  -- 10
          , cookies 1 chocolate 1   -- 15
          , cookies 1 chocolate 1 cookies 100000  -- 1000015
          ]

main :: IO ()
main = print goodies
```

...giving `[10,15,1000015]`.

I don't know if Hugs supports the `TypeFamilies` extension that's needed for the equational constraints `f ~ (Int -> Int)` and `i ~ Int`.

---

What I suspect the **task** is going for is something entirely different, namely, how to *implement* `cookies :: Int -> Int` without using either addition nor multiplication, i.e. without writing `*10` nor `10 + cookies (n-1)`. The answer they probably want should use only the [`succ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ) and `pred` functions (which are equivalent to `+1` and `-1`, respectively).

Comment: Hi! thank you for your response!

"What's wrong with cookies 1 + chocolate 2"
My professor's very specific about stuff and he wants us to do cookies 1 chocolate 2 instead :(

i tried what you typed out but hugs unfortunately does not support that extension. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Ugh. That's an absurd requirement! But well, now you have one crippled solution that allows the exact syntax `cookies 1 chocolate 1` (but nothing else) and also works in Hugs, and one ridiculous typeclass-hackery solution that allows anything of the form `crumble a crumble b ... crumble ω`. Let them choose...

Comment: @Mel That looks as a very unusual requirement. Double check the assignment, since it seems unreasonable to require that `cookies 1 chacolate 2` works. Maybe the professor forgot the `+`? If possible I'd write to the professor and ask to confirm that. From a teaching point of view, it seems a very pointless exercise, since its solution requires to abuse the typeclass machinery, which is not something that should be taught.

Comment: @chi yeah i checked again and that's what he's requiring. i dont think it's a mistake since he gave 5 examples. All of which had no operator

Comment: @leftaroundabout: exactly what i thought :( oh well thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Mel Are you sure your professor is asking for the *Haskell term* `cookies 1 chocolate 2` to work, and not asking you to write a program which accepts `cookies 1 chocolate 2` as input? The latter is significantly easier (and significantly closer to the kind of assignment I could imagine giving to beginners).

Comment: @DanielWagner that is actually what I was trying to ask here so I guess I might've worded things out wrong. He's asking us to input something like `cookies 1 chocolate 2` which should give a result of 20. I got to 'partially' do it as stated above but I dont exactly know how else to go around it

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to write functions named `cookies` and `chocolate` which, when typed into the hugs interpreter, behave that way.

Instead, try to write an `IO` action which accepts input, parses it, and does the appropriate computation. You may like the `interact` function, which takes a function on `String`s and runs it on things the user types:

```
interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
```

For example, with runhaskell (which is very similar to hugs), the following code:

```
main = interact $ \s ->
    "What is your name?\n" ++
    filter (/='\n') s ++ ", nice to meet you!\n"
```

produces the following interaction:

```
% runhaskell test.hs
What is your name?
Daniel
Daniel, nice to meet you!
```

Note that I pressed the EOF button after typing `Daniel` and pressing enter; on Linux this is ctrl-d but I believe on Windows it is ctrl-z. Note also that nowhere in the code is there a definition for `Daniel` -- this `Daniel` that I typed in is *not* a Haskell term, but rather is input read by running the Haskell term `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Daniel Wagner, I suspect this question is misguided. I find it hard to believe that the assignment is asking for functions `cookies` and `chocolate` that can be combined in this way. Rather, it’s probably asking for a function `calculate :: String -> Int` which accepts the *string* `"cookies 1 chocolate 2"`, parses it, and returns the result.

For that, a solution is pretty simple—so I won’t give it away. Break the problem down into small steps like these:

- `"cookies 1 chocolate 2"`
- `["cookies", "1", "chocolate", "2"]`
- `[("cookies", 1), ("chocolate", 2)]`
- `[10, 10]`
- `20`

Write a function for each step, and a `main` that asks for input and calls these functions to calculate the final result. Bonus points if you consider how to use `Maybe` or `Either` to handle errors in the input, such as an unknown item, a non-numeric quantity, a missing quantity, &c.